# vba programming - delete entire row, not containing

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to macros and VBA, so this might be easy.

I need to filter a list of companies, such that companies not matching branchcode are removed from the excel-tab.

More precisely:

- company.xls contains the full list of companies, where column N, is
  containing branchcodes
- branch.xls, column A contains the branchcodes    of relevance, which
  has to be used to filter the comapnies in    company.xls
- The companies in company.xls that do not have a matching
  branchcode should be removed from tab1 to tab2 of company.xls.

I hope it make sense!?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

```
Function Search_String(x As String) As Boolean
Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim Contained As Boolean
Contained = True

'We use the ActiveSheet but you can replace this with
'Sheets("MySheet")if you want
With Sheets("codes")

    'We select the sheet so we can change the window view
    .Select

    'Set the first and last row to loop through
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    'We loop from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

        'We check the values in the A column in this example
        With .Cells(Lrow, "A") 'Column letter for codes sheet

            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If InStr(x, .Value) Then Contained = False
            End If
        End With
    Next Lrow
End With

Search_String = Contained
End Function


Sub Filtrer()
Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long

With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

With Sheets("search (14)") 'Sheet name with rows to be deleted
    'We select the sheet so we can change the window view
    .Select

    'If you are in Page Break Preview Or Page Layout view go
    'back to normal view, we do this for speed
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

    'Turn off Page Breaks, we do this for speed
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Set the first and last row to loop through
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    'We loop from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

        With .Cells(Lrow, "N") 'Change this to the correct Sheets column that needs deleting
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If Search_String(.Value) Then .EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next Lrow

End With

ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show what code you have already written? I'm happy to help you debug your code and answer questions about how to reference Workbooks, Worksheets and Ranges in your code.  However if all you want is "can you write code for me?" the answer is no. If I was going to solve this problem, I'd bring both data sets into Access. Solving this problem with a query would take 10 minutes max.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have some code. But how do I post it here? Max characters is exceeded.

Comment: Instead of pasting it into a comment, you can click the "edit" link underneath your question and add the code there. There should be plenty of room, but really all you need to do is a minimum example of what you're doing.  For example, are you using the AutoFilter functionality? Are you looping through each row to check it against the list of companies? Are you loading the list into a data structure like an an array or Collection?  If you include a small snippet of your code that answers those kinds of questions, it should be enough.

Comment: Thanks again for responding. I pasted the entire code. I actually made it work, so in fact my question now, is regarding this line of code With Sheets("search (14)" . The thing is, that the macro will be used on a number in a number of different workbooks, which is why the aforementioned code needs to change every time, depending on the name of the sheet. So I was wondering if it is possible to code some sort of dialog box, which asks the user of the macro, to type the name of the worksheet before running the macro? The same property would be nice for this line of code With .Cells(Lrow, "N")

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if i'm wrong .Now you want to let the user input the **sheetname** and **columnName**

Then the following code will help you .

```
Dim SheetName As String
Dim ColumnName As String

SheetName = InputBox("Enter the Sheet Name ?") ' Ex Sheet1
ColumnName = InputBox("Enter the column Name ?") ' Ex N

With Sheets(SheetName) ' Replace this line
With .Cells(Lrow, ColumnName) ' Replace this line
```

Comment: Thanks Sathish. It was exactly what I wanted, and it works great! Thanks again

Comment: I'd love to accept it, however, as I am "new here" I can't before reaching 15 reputation... If I understand correctly?